# Application-specific permissions with Azure AD RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Are Azure's RBAC tools and capabilities appropriate for delineating and enforcing app-specific user permissions?

What I've been seeing is that Azure's RBAC capabilities seem to involve managing Azure resources: BLOB services, storage accounts, app services, etc.

But what I don't see are examples of Azure RBAC being used to manage app- (or domain-) specific permissions, like "Allow the user to approve purchasing this widget" or "Allow user to categorize these items as Foo, Bar, or Baz", or "Allow the user to view financial data only from these company divisions".

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how Azure RBAC works, or what it's used to manage? Can anyone point out examples of Azure role definitions that include permissions like the ones above, or point to documentation of how I might set those up?

Comment: What does the `app` you mean in `app-secific permission`, web app? AD App?

Comment: By "application", I meant the abstract business logic that's reified in a web app or API.  Another way to ask my question would be: what is the proper way to implement business logic permissions (as opposed to Azure or Azure AD-level permissions like "read this blob storage container")?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for application specific permissions which can be achieved, by configuring API permissions in apps, registered in AD. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
So the difference between API Permissions and Role Assignments is as below:

**API Permissions:** 2 types.

1. **Delegated permissions** are appropriate for client apps that access a web API as the signed-in user, and whose access should be restricted to the permissions you select in the next step.

   Delegated permissions are used when authentication is done under user's context and are returned in scope claim of the token.
2. **Application permissions** are for service or daemon-type applications that need to access a web API as themselves, without user interaction for sign-in or consent. Unless you've defined application roles for your web API, this option is disabled.

   App permissions are used when authentication is done under application (service principal) context and are returned in roles claim. For example, if you have a web application, you can configure it to allow access to the user, if the scope claim contains read, otherwise deny access. Or grant write access to application only when roles claim contains write.

You should configure API Permissions when you would like to return the permissions in the Access token. When application consumes the token, it makes authorization decision on the basis of permissions present in the token.

**Role Assignments:**

RBAC is the authorization system you use to manage access to Azure resources. When using RBAC, an administrator grants permissions to roles, and not to individual users or groups. The administrator can then assign roles to different users and groups to control who has access to what content and functionality.

Role assignments are used to assign permission to users/service principals on Azure Resources. In this case authorization is done by Azure and not by the end application which happens in case of API permissions.

Please ref the below articles for detailed explanation with examples.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added